# Plotting column graph with multiple groups using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reshape2

I have dataset below and would like to have the results in the [picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Pw4.png) using ggplot.

```
bar_df 

class   boys  girls   
  a     20     30       
  b     40     30      
  c     50     50       
  d     30     70
```

I tried code below

```
bar_df <- melt(bar_df, id.vars = 'class')

ggplot(bar_df,aes(x = variable,y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Your code starts with errors, `Error: id variables not found in data: class`. Please try your code before (or at least immediately after) posting in a question. In this case, it is resolved with `melt(bar_df, id.vars="class")`. Since it was also referring to what is likely your *real* data object name, it was also not finding the object at all. I fixed both in your question, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `pivot_longer` from `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)    

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-class) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, y=value, x=class)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Or with `melt` (as shown by @r2evans):

```
melt(df, id.vars = 'class') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=value, x=class)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(
    class = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
    boys = c(20L, 40L,
             50L, 30L),
    girls = c(30L, 30L, 50L, 70L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

Comment: Once the OP fixes their `melt`, this works with their `bar_df` without the need for `pivot_longer`.

Comment: @r2evans it worked, thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Gillreath-Brown, it worked thanks